# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Returns Nothing On a Specific Website

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I want to use PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to find and show `span#lblPrice` and `a.color-select-button selected` from [this page](https://meghdadit.com/product/75293/) , and the code I wrote in this regard is:

```
$html = file_get_html('https://meghdadit.com/product/75293/');

foreach ($html->find('span#lblPrice') as $e) {
    $price = $e->outertext;
    echo $price;
    break;
}
foreach ($html->find('a.color-select-button selected') as $e) {
    $color = $e->outertext;
    echo $color;
    break;
}
```

This code works well for other sites but unfortunately does not return any results for this site. Please check this site and see if you notice a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll never get any price content from this web-page since it is loaded with JavaScript. If you want to achieve this, you'll need to use another scraping tool.
Your first reflex when you use SimpleHTMLDom is to echo the HTML you parse to see what the library is able to read ! Even the word تومان isn't read in this case !

```
echo $html = file_get_html('https://meghdadit.com/product/75293/');
```

Answer (score 1):

This happen because you don't have  **span#lblPrice** & **a.color-select-button selected**
in response of

```
file_get_html('https://meghdadit.com/product/75293/');
```